# get unique values using perl

Tags: count, uniq

I have a data frame like this

```
val gene
1 Bra011877
1 Bra011878
1 Bra011767
1 Bra011766
1 Bra011765
2 Bra011743
1 Bra011766
1 Bra011742
1 Bra011669
1 Bra011670
1 Bra011767
```

What i want is to get the number of unique values for each of the corresponding gene like this without sorting the table.

```
val gene
1 Bra011877
1 Bra011878
2 Bra011767
1 Bra011766
1 Bra011765
2 Bra011743
1 Bra011766
1 Bra011742
1 Bra011669
1 Bra011670
```

Can somebody help?

Thanks
Upendra

Comment: in the example 1. 011767 has val 1 and in example 2. 011767 has value 2. How is this possible even though it occurs only once. If you could make your example reflect what you would like to get then it would be useful for the community to offer their knowledge.

Comment: Hi Sai, Sorry for that. I have edited the problem now. So what i basically wants is to count the number of unique counts for each of the gene without having to sort the table. I could do something like cat test.txt | sort | uniq -c, but i don't want to do that and the genes have to be in the same order as original. Thanks....

Comment: so is this something you want to do in Perl? I m thinking maybe to store everything in a hash and increment the value of the hash, something like counter{'Bra011877'}+=val